# Latest file of specified folders in one single command

Tags: shell, vlc

I need to play the latest movie of various different folders in a single command from a linux shell.

The following command works fine for one movie:

```
vlc /folderA/`ls -t *.mov | head -1`
```

Trying to expand the command above to play 2 different movies in 2 different folders... But this command below looks for the wrong movie name:

```
vlc /folderA/`ls -t *.mov | head -1` /folderB/`ls -t *.mov | head -1`
```

Comment: This seems like it should work.Look at the output from `/bin/ls -lt /folderA/*.mov | head -5 && /bin/ls -lt /folderB/*.mov | head -5`. It's likely that your `.mov` in FolderB doesn't have the file-date-time value you think it does. And sorry, this doesn't quite make the bar of `if/then/else` programming code for questions here on StackOverflow. Better to post such questions to [su]. Good luck.

Comment: `ls -t *.mov` lists files in the current directory. This cannot be both `/folderA` and `/folderB` simultaneously

Comment: assuming your filenames do not contain spaces: `vlc $(ls -t /folderA/*.mov | head -1) $(ls -t /folderB/*.mov | head -1)` would make more sense